# Maven EAR dependency structure

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, ear

I'm trying to deploy an EAR to Wildfly 10 via Eclipse Neon with the latest JBoss Tools. This is my first attempt with EARs, so I documented myself and this is the structure I came up with:

Maven modules:

- `api` (type `jar`, no deps): contains the interfaces `MyService` and `Person`.
- `ejb` (type `ejb`, depends on `api`): contains a `@Stateless` implementation of `MyService` and an `@Entity` implementation of `Person`.
- `war` (type `war`, depends on `api`): contains a JAX-RS resource which uses `MyService`.
- `ear` (type `ear`, depends on `ejb` and `war`): the EAR module.

(See here for the full source: https://github.com/heruan/maven-ear-example)

The problem is when I deploy this to Wildfly, I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link ejb/MyServiceImpl: api/MyService
```

Full stack trace:

```
INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment ear-1.0.0.ear
WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-6) Failed to define class ejb.MyServiceImpl in Module "deployment.ear-1.0.0.ear.ejb-1.0.0.jar:main" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link ejb/MyServiceImpl (Module "deployment.ear-1.0.0.ear.ejb-1.0.0.jar:main" from Service Module Loader): api/MyService
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.__newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:446)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:274)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:78)
    at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:606)
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:14)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.processComponentConfig(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:84)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.deploy(InterceptorAnnotationProcessor.java:76)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What am I missing? My goal is to have the most basic EAR with a common JPA Persistence Unit shared by its modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what the problem was: duplicate `.class` files. Seems like the Maven EAR plugin isn't clever enough to avoid duplicate dependencies, so you need to explicitly set them as `provided`.

For example, the solution in the example project is to set the `api` module as `provided` in the `war`'s `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```